# unmatched curly brace in \PVerb argument

Tags: verbatim

I do realize that a verbatim `{` can be obtained by `\verb|{|`. However, I need `\PVerb` which is robust to work in `\item` command.

Obviously, a `\PVerb{{}` won't work. So is there a solution for unmatched `{` in `\PVerb` or is there a workaround to circumvent the problem?

Comment: `\texttt{\{}` is also possible

Comment: If you have just an unmatched brace, ``\texttt{\char`\{}}`` should do; you can just say `\texttt{\{}` if you're loading `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, otherwise the brace will not be in the monospaced font.

Comment: @Herbert Thanks, I have already used it as workaround. :-)

Comment: @egreg thanks, I actually learned to load `fontenc` from another answer of yours. But at the moment I cannot figure out which. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using package `examplep`, then `\Q` could be used, that supports escaping:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[Q=yes]{examplep}

\begin{document}
  \begin{description}
  \item[\Q{\\textbf\{...\}}] Bold.
  \end{description}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thanks so much, `\Q` is amazing in both Star Trek and LaTeX world. :-P

Comment: @Naitree And don't forget `\Q` in the world of James Bond, either.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: Toy maker for lesser beings? Star Trek's `\Q` only snips with a finger. :-)

Answer (score 3):

No need for invasive packages:

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareRobustCommand\Q[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \ttfamily
  \def\{{\char`\{}%
  \def\}{\char`\}}%
  \def\\{\char`\\}%
  #1%
  \endgroup}

\begin{document}

\section{Here \Q{\\textit\{...\}}}

\begin{description}
\item[\Q{\\textbf\{...\}}] Bold.
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]